# delay form input function by 3 seconds before executing

Tags: jquery, forms, function, delay

I am not that great with `js` as it stands and slowly starting to get to grips with it: I have a small (working) webcam app that takes a pic and inserts the base64 into the (hidden) #formfield b4 posting the form ->

```
button code:
<input type="image" src="images/takepic.jpg"  id="btn1" onclick="base64_tofield()">


function base64_tofield() {

                $('#formfield').val($.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
};
```

what I need is a div to display a countdown 3.. 2.. 1 (seconds) before the button actually submits - is there a way to delay this function by 3 seconds and have the timer?-  its so ppl can get ready for pic..

I have tried this

```
setTimeout(function() { base64_tofield() },5000);
```

In various places but not working - it still takes immediately. The countdown div ill have to add and serves no other function than just counting down so the user has time to prepare.

The button grabs the base64 data into the formfield AND submits the form.. i thought perhaps delaying the function would delay the form but it doesnt, i think what i need is to delay the form by 3.5 seconds -and the function by 3.. so when the user clicks "Take picture" the timer starts, and after 3 seconds - the function base64_tofield() triggers (taking the pic) and then 1/2 second later the form submits..

it just gives the user time to prepare for the gimmick shot before submitting

Comment: wait.. is this scriptcam plugin able to capture my webcam without asking me? Can this be put into a hidden frame? Sounds voodoo or anti-privacy to me

Comment: there should be a flash player window with allow/deny - its for a promo comp.. scriptcam is quite popular

Answer (score 0):

Just wraps everything into `setTimeout` JS timer...

```
setTimeout(base64_tofield(), 2000);
```

...or you can use `delay()` function on submit.

Comment: will that also delay the actual picture being taken? could u show the full code - i wouldnt know where to wrap the function - sorry my js is pitiful -

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false in your onclick function or the form will be posted immediately. Alternatively, you can bind to the submit event using jQuery, and use event.preventDefault();

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <div id="countdown"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="encryptedImage" id="formfield" />
    <input id="submitform" type="submit" name="capture" value="capture"></input>
</form>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
        base64_tofield();
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    function base64_tofield() {
        var interval;
        var countdown = 4;

        interval = setInterval(function() {
            $('#countdown').html(--countdown);
            if(countdown === 0){
                $('#formfield').val($.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
                $('#form1')[0].submit();
            };
        }, 1000);
    };
});
</script>
```

If I've understood you correctly, the above code will do what you want, waiting 3 seconds before submitting the form.

Comment: tx - close, the extra second is just to allow time between the actual capturing of the image data and the form submission. At the mo its pretty much working - so i dounbt the .5 sec is necessary - anyway, the form is still cracking away - no delay. Im assuming i give the form an id and alter your $('#idofform').submit(); to reflect this?

Comment: Yes that's right. I've simplified the example and got it working at this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/URvdU/1/ I've updated my answer to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="countdown" value="3" />
<input type="button" id="begincountdown" value="Start Countdown" />

<script>
    function base64_tofield() {
       console.log( 'Encode!' );   
    }

    $('#begincountdown').on( 'click', function() {
        var secondscounter = 3,
            countdown = setInterval(function(){ 
                $('#countdown').val( secondscounter-- );
                if ( !secondscounter ) {
                  clearInterval( countdown ); 
                  base64_tofield();
                }
        }, 3000 );
    });
</script>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/XytRt/27/